# How to search by coordinates in Apple Maps?

Tags: macos, maps

Using google maps, looking for `N45°11.760 E5°45.936` works to show the geolocation on a map.

Unfortunately this does not work on Maps.

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it seems that Maps only want decimals : `45.196000, 5.765600`

Too bad it isn't as flexible as GMaps.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most elegant solution, but it does work!

1. Drop a pin where you want the coordinates
2. Hit the info and then share button
3. Pick something likes messages, etc. Right click on the link that gets created and hit 'edit link'. You'll see the latitude and longitude as parameters in the URL. For example: http://maps.apple.com/?lsp=9902&auid=4158007438164491913&sll=38.897517,-77.036542&q=The%20White%20House&hnear=38.897517,-77.036542

Latitude and Longitude are right there in the URL params.

Comment: Instead of going through messages, you can also choose _Edit > Copy Link_ to place the URL in the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

To get the co ordinates without the clutter...

Drop Pin
Share to Messages,
Right click on the word 'map' and select 'open link'

The coordinates will now appear in the search field of Maps.app

Answer (score 0):

Easy Method works in Maps and Mavericks.

1 Drop Pin

2 Share to Messages

3 Ctrl click on the word 'Map' in messages.app and then select 'Open'.

The co-ordinates will now appear in the search field of Apple Maps.